# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable from main

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote a code which is going to store occurrences of words from a text file and store it to a dictionary:

```
class callDict(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.invertedIndex = {}
```

then I write a method

```
def invertedIndex(self):
        print self.invertedIndex.items()
```

and here is how I am calling:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = callDict()
    c.invertedIndex()
```

But it gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E\Project\xyz.py", line 56, in <module>
    c.invertedIndex()
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are defining a method and an instance variable in your code, both with the same name. This will result in a name clash and hence the error.

Change the name of one or the other to resolve this.

So for example, this code should work for you:

```
class CallDict(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inverted_index = {}
    def get_inverted_index_items(self):
        print self.inverted_index.items()
```

And check it using:

```
>>> c = CallDict()
>>> c.get_inverted_index_items()
[]
```

---

Also check out [ozgur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28505749/1860929) for doing this using [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)  decorator.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [mu's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28505711/793428) answer,

```
@property
def invertedIndexItems(self):
    print self.invertedIndex.items()
```

then here is how you'll cal it:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = callDict()
    print c.invertedIndexItems
```

Answer (score 1):

Methods are attributes in Python, so you can't share the same name between them.  Rename one of them.